# How can I add CSS code to pre built themes in Website builder

Tags: html, css

Website builder name: Dynadot not Wordspace SO I CANNOT MAKE A CHILD THEME
I want css code for my website P.S The website has prebuilt themes and we can basically customize text, change pictures, add products etc. The website also provides a CSS editor like square space does. I have been to so many websites to try to copy some code but not a success. I have no experience with it either. Here is some information that might be useful.Also, the first pictures has drag and drop options like i can drag VIDEO to a certain part Here is a example website: https://www.svpartners.com/ I don't want the image animation it already has i need some new ideas on how to customize it with CSS, Font for the website Open sans
The screenshot 1 shows how my website theme already looks also at the bottom left there is a code option and there is a screen shot #2 for it so it might be helpful. Again I have tried many sites but most ask for money and most are not helpful. ALSO a GIF so you can have a better view please help me out thanks

[THE GIF](https://ibb.co/QbQxT92)

I am new here, I don't know how this works! Just ignore the writing if it'd not good, Also comment if you need any more details

Comment: The best way to modify css of prebuilt template is to make [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) of your prebuilt theme which can have his own css. This way you can change css of template as you like without the need to worry about overwriting changes with theme update. This css file you can modify via FTP or in "theme editor" in wordpress admin panel

Comment: HI @ciekals11 I don't know how to do it, would you have any videos or something like it that could help?

Comment: Search for `child theme wordpress` in google and you will get a dozen of tutorials on how to do it

Comment: ok Thanks. i will look at it

Comment: @ciekals11 I don't have a Plugins options in my website builder. My website builder is Dynadot

Comment: Ok. So I was wrong. I have assumed that you are working with wordpress which now i get that you don't. Sorry mate, i don't know this tool, cannot help.